# Is there a workaround for "incompatible parameter list" message from Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2009, ambiguity

Please consider this simplified example:

```
type
  TForm43 = class(TForm)
    drwgrd1: TDrawGrid;
    procedure drwgrd1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; 
      Rect: Windows.TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm43.drwgrd1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: Windows.TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  Rect.Left := 5;
end;
```

In method `drwgrd1DrawCell` I've explicitly used `Windows.TRect` to resolve ambiguity beetween `TRect` defined in two different units. Everything works fine, code is compiling.
But everytime when I save the above unit I am getting a question from the Delphi IDE which asks: "*The drwgrd1DrawCell method referenced by drwgrd1.OnDrawCell has an incompatible parameter list. Remove the reference?*"

This is very annoying. Is there any way to turn off this message dialog or to write my code in a  way that it would not be shown? Unfortunately I can not change my `TRect` for `TRect2` or something like that.

Comment: Maybe reversing the order in which the used units are listed might help?

Comment: Alternatively you can attach the handler at run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error when you save the form is because Delphi compares the declaration of all event handlers to ensure they are declare exactly the same as their inherited implementations.  Adding `Windows.` to the declaration makes the compare fail.

You can remove the `Windows.` from `drwgd1DrawCell()` if you move the `Windows` unit after the other unit in the `uses` clause that declares `TRect`.  This is because Delphi processes the units in the `uses` clause from the last to the first.  It will use the `TRect` from the first instance that it finds...

Answer (score 4):

You could add the following type declaration above your form declaration:

```
    type
      TRect = Windows.TRect;
```

Comment: And then change the `Rect` parameter to be just `TRect` instead of `Windows.TRect`.

Comment: @Wodzu, you tell that dumm's answer works, but you mark James' answer as correct. So what was the real answer for you ?

Comment: @Arioch'The both answers have worked for me. I've marked James' answer as correct because it was the first one that came up.